# convert ipython notebook to presentation with cells contents hidden

Tags: ipython, presentation, reveal.js

Is it possible currently to convert IPython notebook to presentation so only output of each cell is visible on the slide? e.g. if I want to show plot, but don't want to show lines of code for plotting it?

Thanks!

Update:

It seems that adding

```
div.input.hbox, div.prompt.output_prompt {
    display: none;
}
```

to `customs.css` does the trick. 
I wonder if it possible to hide these items on slide-basis.

Answer (score 1):

Making this on slide-basis implies write an extension to make it possible...